# Video-Output of time-dependent PDE

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I plot a time-dependent function in MATLAB by drawing a snapshot in "each" time step, the interval is discretized.

Is is possible to save this plot as a video?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy. Use the `VideoWriter` function:

Initialize the file by `v = VideoWriter('filename.avi');` and `open(v);`. Then do your plotting and in each timestep write your plot to the file:

```
for K=1:20
    %...plot....%
    frame = getframe(gcf);
    writeVideo(v,frame); 
end

close(v);
```

Your movie is saved in the folder you're in.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `im2frame` `movie` and `VideoWriter` in the documentation. They should do what you need to create and save this video in your preferred format.